# Optimization Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I have an optimization issue that I'm not sure where to go from here. I have a program that tries to find the best combination of inputs that return the highest predicted r squared value. The problem is that I have 21 total inputs (List) and I need them in a set of 15 inputs. The formula for total combinations is:

n! / r!(n - r)! = 21! / 15!(21 - 15)! = 54,264 possible combinations

So obviously running through each combination and calculating the predicted rsquared is not an ideal solution so is there an better way/algorithm/method I can use to try to skip or narrow down the bad combinations so that I'm only processing the fewest amount of combinations? Here is my current psuedo code for this issue:

```
public BestCombo GetBestCombo(List<List<MultipleRegressionInfo>> combosList)
{
   BestCombo bestCombo = new BestCombo();

   foreach (var combo in combosList)
   {
      var predRsquared = CalculatePredictedRSquared(combo);

      if (predRsquared > bestCombo.predRSquared)
      {
         bestCombo.predRSquared = predRsquared;
         bestCombo.BestRSquaredCombo = combo;
      }
   }

   return bestCombo;
}

public class BestCombo
    {
        public double predRSquared { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MultipleRegressionInfo> BestRSquaredCombo { get; set; }
    }

public class MultipleRegressionInfo
{
    public List<double> input { get; set; }
    public List<double> output { get; set; }
}

public double CalculatePredictedRSquared(List<MultipleRegressionInfo> combo)
{
    Matrix<double> matrix = BuildMatrix(combo.Select(i => i.input).ToArray());
    Vector<double> vector = BuildVector(combo.ElementAt(0).output);
    var coefficients = CalculateWithQR(matrix, vector);
    var y = CalculateYIntercept(coefficients, input, output);
    var estimateList = CalculateEstimates(coefficients, y, input, output);
    return GetPredRsquared(estimateList, output);
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to maximize r^2 value, one thing you could do is compute the overall r squared first. Next, calculate the difference between predicted and actual values. Now only use the 15 smallest residuals. Recomputing your r^2 one more time should yield you actual r^2. Trying to compute the best r^2 brute force is going to take forever. I believe my theoretical algorithm would have O(n^3) complexity if you use normal arrays. Using trees or other datastructures may reduce the complexity.

Comment: @BennettYeo I edited my question to show more pseudo code because what I'm currently doing is getting the overall rsquared for all of the inputs in the current combo and at the end, I output the combo that has the best rsquared. Hopefully this helps explains things a bit better unless I'm misunderstanding what you are suggesting. Can you show me pseudo code for what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Rufus oops I just fixed that

Comment: Given two combinations is there a way to tell which one is the better?

Comment: @eric Yes the combo that has a higher overall rsquared would be the better one between the two

Comment: @user3610374: I phrased that inelegantly. Obviously doing the computation tells you. I meant to ask questions like: (1) is there a *cheap* way to know which of the two is better?  (2) Suppose we have three combos, and we've computed r-squared for two of them. Is there ever a way to look at the third combo and compare it to the first two without computing r-squared again, and know if it is going to be between them?  Suppose for example the three combos each differ in only one place.

Comment: @user3610374 It's hard for me to write explicit psuedo code, because I don't know how whether you're using a fully written library to calculate r squared or if you wrote you own method. R squared is usually derived from a linear fit model. If you know the model `y(x) = mx + b` you can use that to do a [residual analysis](http://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=Residual%20plot) and knock off the values that are the farthest away from the predicted line of best fit.

Comment: What I'm getting at is: optimization algorithms almost always involve being able to either "prune" combinations that you know are going to be bad, or "hill climb" going from one good combination to a better combination, until you find the best.

Comment: @bennett I am using the math.net library to calculate the multiple regression rsquared for each combo

Comment: @eric I can't think of a cheap way to determine how good the combo would be without calculating rsquared. I have been racking my brain trying to think of ideas on how to do it. The only idea I can think of would be to Hill climb in a way and compare the current combo rsquared to the current one and if it goes down then find the difference with the inputs and if it is a single input that is different then removing all combos using that input because obviously that input has a negative effect. Hopefully I explained that well

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the [MultipleRegressionInfo](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearRegression/MultipleRegression.htm) I think you may be able to obtain a linear fit model from the `Vector<T> DirectMethod<T>(Matrix<T> x, Vector<T> y, DirectRegressionMethod method)`

Comment: From there: `Residual = Observed value - Predicted value` do this for each value in the dataset, then knock of the values in your dataset with the biggest residual value.

Comment: @BennettYeo It isn't perfect by any stretch of the imagination but I just edited my code to show a psuedo code version of my calculatersquared method where I essentially get the rsquared by using the math.net library and the rsquared is essentially the squared sum of the observed value - predicted value so what it sounds like you are saying is get the individual rsquared value for each of the 21 inputs and eliminate the lowest ones?

Comment: Yes, and Eliminate the highest and lowest ones. Do Residual = Absolute_Value(Observed value - Predicted Value). The farther away a point is from the line of best fit, the higher it's absolute residual value will be. The +/- part of a residual shows whether the data-point under or over estimates the cruve but we don't care about that as much. Technically speaking an "individual sqrt(rsquared) value" is just a residual.

Comment: @BennettYeo I tried a similar method to what I believe you are talking about at first but the issue I came across is that sometimes a single input that had a lower rsquared value than the rest would sometimes increase the overall rsquared value of the combo. The problem with multiple regression is choosing the right combo of inputs that account for as much of the variablility in the output as possible. If I'm not understanding what you are suggesting then please correct me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159201/discussion-between-bennett-yeo-and-user3610374).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

54,264 is not enormous for a computer - it might be worth timing a few calls to compute R^2 and multiplying up to see just how long this would take.

There is a branch and bound algorithm for this sort of problem, which relies on the fact that R^2(A,B,C) >= R^2(A,B) - that the R^2 can only decrease when you drop a variable. Recursively search the space of all sets of variables of size at least 15. After computing the R^2 for a set of variables, make recursive calls with sets produced by dropping a single variable from the set, where any such drop must be to the right of any existing gap (so A.CDE produces A..DE, A.C.E, and A.CD. but not ..CDE, which will be produced by .BCDE). You can terminate the recursion when you get down to the desired size of set, or when you find an R^2 that is no better than the best answer so far.

If it happens that you often find R^2 values no better than the best answer so far, this will save time - but this is not guaranteed. You can attempt to improve the efficiency by chosing to investigate the sets with highest R^2 first, hoping that you find a new best answer good enough to rule out their siblings by the time you come to them, and by using a procedure to calculate R^2 for A.CDE that makes use of the calculations you have already done for ABCDE.

Comment: I apologize for not specifying better and I amended my question but I'm calculate predicted rsquared because regular rsquared will just keep going up as you add more inputs but predicted rsquared is much better for verifying if your data is good for future predictions.

Comment: FWIW because the standard R^2 is always higher than any adjusted R^2, a standard R^2 value for A,B,C is still an upper bound on the adjusted value for A,B: standard A,B,C >= standard A,B >= adjusted A,B. Of course this bound may be too loose to be of any practical use.

Comment: So there are some issues with your answer. I'm calculating predicted rsquared and not adjusted rsquared. Predicted rsquared takes out one datapoint at a time and recalculates the remaining datapoints again for the best fit line to get an estimate for the missing datapoint and then adds up all residuals for every datapoint so for example if I have 4000 datapoints for the input then that is 4000 * 54,264 = 217,056,000 so that is why I need to be optimizing this process. I get what you are recommending but it wouldn't work with predicted rsquared

Comment: If you are calculating predicted r^2 by recalculating from scratch for every data point you can save some time. See for example http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/Regression/RegressionDiagnostics/OlsHatMatrix.pdf equation 30 P 10. If you work through this document from the beginning you will see an explanation of this and a definition of the hat matrix equation 8 P 3. The hat matrix is of size n^2 but looking at that equation I think you can save time calculating it by only calculating the diagonal from X and (X'X)^-1X'. See also https://www.otexts.org/1580